# Ruby on Rails complex forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms

I am developing a content management system for the needs of my client and I am stuck. I have to create a system in order to manage products and their prices. The project is for a tourist agency so every "product price" has seasons, and for each season there is a product category. Each product category has the prices. For example:

I am "creating" a hotel (the product). I must also create the "price periods" (low season, mid season etc). In each price period I create a price category (for example "Gold Club Rooms") and in each category I create the room price (for example "Double Deluxe - 100$"). The price_periods, price_groups and prices are all models with association to the product. My problem is that I have to create all these in one form. I thought of a way but it is pretty complex and I did not manage, yet, to make it work properly...

In few words, I created a two step submission. One for the product and the price_periods, and a second step for the price_category and price (in a triple nested form). I am looking for a more clean way to build this so I am asking for help. **Is there a design pattern I should follow? Or a book or reference?**

Please help :) Sorry if this is "Out of subject", but I am really stuck and would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

my models are:

## Product

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Concerns 
  include Translatable
  translates :title, :description, :address

  # Validations
  validates_presence_of :address_lat, :address_lon

  # Associations

  has_and_belongs_to_many :product_categories
  has_many :product_translations
  has_many :prices
  has_many :price_periods
  has_many :price_groups
  belongs_to :location
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_translations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :prices
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :price_periods
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :price_groups
end
```

## Price Period

```
class PricePeriod < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Associations
  has_many :prices
  belongs_to :product
end
```

## Price Group

```
class PriceGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Associations
  has_many :prices
  belongs_to :product
end
```

## Price

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Associations
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :price_group
  belongs_to :price_period
end
```

Comment: Could you maybe post your migrations and models?

Comment: I think you need something like angular/ember/backbone for clean way to build UI like yours. I prefer angular. But choice is yours.

Comment: I have added my models. I have used angular in the past, but I try to avoid it. In this project I used pure jquery along with some plugins. I mostly need the architecture pattern to do this. I will try angular though, just in case :) Thanks. Any other suggestion for architectural/design pattern.